# Continuous function to approximate square root

Tags: calculus, approximation

I have the following function

$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{x} &\quad\forall \ x >= 0 \\
-\sqrt{-x} &\quad\forall \ x < 0 \end{cases}$

[You can find a plot of the function here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz7wM.png)

I'm using this function within an optimization problem. Since the "if" clause on the value of $x$ is necessary to determine which of the two functions needs to be applied, the problem becomes a binary optimization problem, which is computationally a lot more tedious to solve than a problem with continuous variables.

Therefore, I'd like to approximate the function with a continuous function. So far, I've played around with polynomial fits and Taylor functions, but nothing really approximated my function well, especially in the area around $x=0$.

Would anyone have a suggestion for me on how to tackle this problem? How can I find a continuous function, which is applicable for both positive and negative $x$, to approximate my function? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: $f$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Note that the function's derivative goes to infinity as $x$ approaches zero.

Comment: Ok, please let me rephrase that then: I'd like to approximate the aforementioned function without having any "cases", just one representation that applies for all x from minus infinity to plus infinity. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps $(x/|x|)\sqrt{|x|},$ with some care when evaluating exactly at $0$?

Comment: $sign(x) \sqrt{|x|}$ or $\frac{x}{\sqrt{|x|}}$

Comment: @MotiNisenson I've been there, but having an absolute function in there somehow still causes numerical issues for my optimization (maybe because the absolute itself is not continuously differentiable, and hence gradient based methods struggle here). I appreciate all inputs up to now, but I'm looking for a function which contains no absolutes and no "cases". I am aware that I'll most likely need to do some sort of (ugly...) approximation - I'm looking for inputs on how to narrow down my options in terms of model to fit to my problem

Comment: Something like $\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^2}}$?